# Unexpected duplicates ajax call after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I click .add button which is added dynamicly I call ajax to make a select from data but when I m in first module and click is okey , but when next I go to second module and click I`v got duplicates ajax call and added more that one filter I dont know where I do a mistake so please help me to resolve it

Here`s code:

One module:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("select").select2();
            var $toggleColumns = $('.toggleColumns');
            var datatableName = "list";
            var $body = $("body");
            var URL = 'xxx';
            var columns = [
                {'data': 'title', 'class': "datatable-row-title"},
                {'class': '',
                    'orderable': false,
                    "mData": "comment_type_value", "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        if (data > 0) {
                            return '<label class="details-control" style="width:100%; height:100%;"> ' + translate('t_expand_comment_type_down') + ' </label>';
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }


                    },
                },
                {'mData': 'item', "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return data;
                    }},
                {'data': 'seller'},
                {'data': 'buyer'},
                {'data': 'cat'},
                {'data': 'comment_type'},
                {'data': 'startts'},
                {'data': 'endts'},
                {'data': 'ts'},
                {'data': 'price'},
                {'data': 'qty'},
                {'data': 'sales'},
            ];
            var order = [];

    <?php if (isset($_GET["filters"])): ?>
                URL_TMP = URL;
                URL_TMP += "?insert=false";
                getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL_TMP, columns, order, "transaction");
                URL_TMP = "";
    <?php else: ?>
                getButtonsAfterAdded();
                $body.on("click", ".toggleColumnsButton", function (e) {
                    $("#columnsContainer").toggle("slow");
                    return false;
                });
                $body.on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                    getButtonsAfterRemove();


                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {

                        var validate = validateTransaction();

                        if (validate.status == false) {
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                                text: validate.msg,
                                class_name: 'danger',
                                time: '5000'
                            });
                            loader.popup("hide");
                            return false;
                        }

                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "transaction");
                    }


                    resetSelect2();

                });
                $body.on("change", ".commentType", function () {
                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "transaction");
                    }
                });
                $body.on("change", ".categories", function () {
                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "transaction");
                    }
                });
                $body.on('click', ".add", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var filterID = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").attr("data-filteroptionid");
                    $(".filters").append(filtersHTMLTransactionSelect(filterID));
                    var filterId = $(".filter:last-child .chooseFilter option:not(:disabled)").attr("data-filterOptionId");
                    $(".filter").last().prepend("<div class='col-sm-4 form-group sibling'>" + filtersHTMLTransactionValues(filterId) + "</div>");
                    $(".filter").last().append(getCollectionOfButtons());

                    resetSelect2();

                    transactionDatepicker();

                    getButtonsAfterAdded();

                });

                $body.on("keypress", function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        loader.popup("show");
                        var validate = validateTransaction();

                        if (validate.status == false) {
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                                text: validate.msg,
                                class_name: 'danger',
                                time: '5000'
                            });
                            loader.popup("hide");
                            return false;
                        }
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "transaction");
                    }
                });

                $body.on('click', ".search", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateTransaction();
                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "transaction");
                });

                $toggleColumns.on('click', function (e) {
                    var column = $('#' + datatableName).DataTable().column($(this).attr('data-column'));
                    column.visible(!column.visible());
                });


                $(".csv").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateTransaction();

                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "xxxx",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            filters: getActiveFiltersTransaction(),
                            format: 1,
                            module_id: <?php echo \kontrola\TransactionActions::$MODULE_ID; ?>
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            getAccessMessageWithStatusDataTable(response);
                            getUses();
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: translate('gritter_title_raports'),
                                text: $("#waitingTimeForFile").html(),
                                class_name: 'success'
                            });
                            $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                "color": "red"
                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.nav-quirk").find("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                    color: "#505b72"
                                });
                                $.gritter.removeAll();
                            }, 15000);
                        }
                    });
                });

                $(".xls").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateTransaction();

                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "xxx",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            filters: getActiveFiltersTransaction(),
                            format: 0,
                            module_id: <?php echo \kontrola\TransactionActions::$MODULE_ID; ?>
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            getAccessMessageWithStatusDataTable(response);
                            getUses();

                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: translate('gritter_title_raports'),
                                text: $("#waitingTimeForFile").html(),
                                class_name: 'success'
                            });
                            $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                "color": "red"
                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.nav-quirk").find("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                    color: "#505b72"
                                });
                                $.gritter.removeAll();
                            }, 15000);
                        }
                    });
                });

                $body.on("click", "#raportsScroll", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var top = $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").offset().top;
                    top = 241 - 65;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: top
                    }, 1000);
                });

                $body.on("change", ".chooseFilter", function () {
                    var filterId = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-filterOptionId");
                    $(this).parent().prev().html(filtersHTMLTransactionValues(filterId));
                    //                transactionDefaultStateOptions();
                    transactionDatepicker();
                    resetSelect2();
                });
    <?php endif; ?>
        });
```

Another module:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("select").select2();
            var $toggleColumns = $('.toggleColumns');
            var datatableName = "list";
            var $body = $("body");
            var URL = 'xxx';
            var columns = [
                {'data': 'title', 'class': "datatable-row-title"},
                {'mData': 'item', "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                        return data;
                    }},
                {'data': 'price'},
                {'data': 'qty'},
                {'data': 'user'},
                {'data': 'cat'},
                {'data': 'startts'},
                {'data': 'endts'}
            ];
            var order = [];
            getButtonsAfterAdded();
    <?php if (isset($_GET["filters"])): ?>
                URL_TMP = URL;
                URL_TMP += "?insert=false";
                getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL_TMP, columns, order, "auction");
                URL_TMP = "";
    <?php else: ?>

                $body.on("click", ".toggleColumnsButton", function (e) {
                    $("#columnsContainer").toggle("slow");
                    return false;
                });
                $body.on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

                    getButtonsAfterRemove();


                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {

                        var validate = validateAuction();

                        if (validate.status == false) {
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                                text: validate.msg,
                                class_name: 'danger',
                                time: '5000'
                            });
                            loader.popup("hide");
                            return false;
                        }

                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "auction");
                    }


                    $("select").select2("destroy");
                    $("select").select2();

                });
                $body.on("change", ".commentType", function () {
                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "auction");
                    }
                });
                $body.on("change", ".categories", function () {
                    if ($("#list tbody tr").length > 0) {
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "auction");
                    }
                });
                $body.on('click', ".add", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var filterID = $(this).parent().prev().find("option:selected").attr("data-filteroptionid");
                    $(".filters").append(filtersHTMLAuctionSelect(filterID));
                    var filterId = $(".filter:last-child .chooseFilter option:not(:disabled)").attr("data-filterOptionId");
                    $(".filter").last().prepend("<div class='col-sm-4 form-group sibling'>" + filtersHTMLAuctionValues(filterId) + "</div>");
                    $(".filter").last().append(getCollectionOfButtons());

                    $("select").select2("destroy");
                    $("select").select2();

                    auctionDatepicker();

                    getButtonsAfterAdded();

                });

                $body.on("keypress", function (e) {
                    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                        loader.popup("show");
                        var validate = validateAuction();

                        if (validate.status == false) {
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                                text: validate.msg,
                                class_name: 'danger',
                                time: '5000'
                            });
                            loader.popup("hide");
                            return false;
                        }
                        getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "auction");
                    }
                });

                $body.on('click', ".search", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateAuction();
                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    getAjaxDatatable(datatableName, URL, columns, order, "auction");
                });

                $toggleColumns.on('click', function (e) {
                    var column = $('#' + datatableName).DataTable().column($(this).attr('data-column'));
                    column.visible(!column.visible());
                });


                $(".csv").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateAuction();

                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "xxx",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            filters: getActiveFiltersAuction(),
                            format: 1,
                            module_id: <?php echo \kontrola\AuctionActions::$MODULE_ID; ?>
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            getAccessMessageWithStatusDataTable(response);
                            getUses();
                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: translate('gritter_title_raports'),
                                text: $("#waitingTimeForFile").html(),
                                class_name: 'success'
                            });
                            $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                "color": "red"
                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.nav-quirk").find("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                    color: "#505b72"
                                });
                                $.gritter.removeAll();
                            }, 15000);
                        }
                    });
                });

                $(".xls").on("click", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var validate = validateAuction();

                    if (validate.status == false) {
                        $.gritter.add({
                            title: tranlate("gritter_title_validate"),
                            text: validate.msg,
                            class_name: 'danger',
                            time: '5000'
                        });
                        return false;
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "xxxx",
                        dataType: "JSON",
                        data: {
                            filters: getActiveFiltersAuction(),
                            format: 0,
                            module_id: <?php echo \kontrola\AuctionActions::$MODULE_ID; ?>
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            getAccessMessageWithStatusDataTable(response);
                            getUses();

                            $.gritter.add({
                                title: translate('gritter_title_raports'),
                                text: $("#waitingTimeForFile").html(),
                                class_name: 'success'
                            });
                            $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                "color": "red"
                            });
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.nav-quirk").find("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").css({
                                    color: "#505b72"
                                });
                                $.gritter.removeAll();
                            }, 15000);
                        }
                    });
                });

                $body.on("click", "#raportsScroll", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var top = $("[data-controller-name=raportsDownloaded]").offset().top;
                    top = 241 - 65;
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: top
                    }, 1000);
                });

                $body.on("change", ".chooseFilter", function () {
                    var filterId = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-filterOptionId");
                    $(this).parent().prev().html(filtersHTMLAuctionValues(filterId));
                    auctionDefaultStateOptions();
                    auctionDatepicker();
                    $("select").select2("destroy");
                    $("select").select2();

                });
    <?php endif; ?>
        });


<?php endif; ?>
```

Ajax call function looks like:

```
function filtersHTMLAuctionSelect() {
    var filters = "";
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "xxxxx",
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
            filters += "<div class='filter'><div class='col-sm-4 form-group'>";
            filters += "<select class='form-control chooseFilter' style='width: 100%;'>";
            $.each(response, function (index, value) {
                filters += "<option data-filterOptionId=" + value.id + ">" + translate(value.title) + "</option>";
            });
            filters += "</select>";
        }
    });
    filters += "</div></div>";
    return filters;
}
```

Okey I resolve problem by added that to buttons added dynamicly:

```
$body.off('click', '#add').on('click', "#add", function (e) {
$body.off('click', '#search').on('click', "#add", function (e) {
```

It work for me.

HTML group of buttons:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <button class="add btn btn-success btn-quirk col-sm-3" id="add"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <button class="search btn btn-warning btn-quirk col-sm-3" id="search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: you should use `id` instead of `class`. when there are multiple but kind of same ajax calls

Comment: Look up for edit I add id but still the same

Comment: nice php in javascript :))

Comment: dumb question why did you duplicate the code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to stop propagation as well, this might be an issue of bubbling.

So when you call

```
e.preventDefault();
```

also call stop propagation which will make your code look like this:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

You can read more here: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

EDIT:

Another thing that might go wrong is here:

```
$body.on('click', "#add", function (e) {
```

Try using

```
$('#add').on('click', function (e) {
```

Comment: Look edit. I`v add propagation but still the same I try it before

Comment: Sorry indentation made me overlook this one. Checkout edit.

Comment: When I do that I cant catch event click dynamicly so in new buttons add is not working but is okey added onyl one filter not duplicates

Comment: @thanpa the edit doesn't apply because he sad he has dynamically added elements

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this issue appears if we make a ajax call on an element that contain children inside it and function call repeatedly for children also. And try thanpa solution - `$('#add').on('click', function (e) {`

Comment: @up that solution not working I sad I added buttons dynamicly

Comment: if you are adding button dynamically then you can use <button onClick="Your FunctionName" > and make the ajax call from this function.